# Write a simple python script to convert all .wav files in a specific folder to .mp3 using lame

Tags: python, audio, mp3, lame

I'd like to write a simple script to convert a few dozen .wav files I have in a folder to v0 mp3. It doesn't need to be complicated, just enough to do the job and help me learn a little bit of python in the process ;)

I've gathered that I'll need to use something like "from subprocess import call" to do the calling of "lame", but I'm stuck as to how I can write the rest. I've written bash scripts to do this before, but on windows they're not much good to me.

I understand basic python programming.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample that works on Ubuntu Linux at least. If you're on Windows, you'll need to change the direction of the slashes.

```
import os
import os.path
import sys
from subprocess import call

def main():
    path = '/path/to/directory/'
    filenames = [
        filename
        for filename
        in os.listdir(path)
        if filename.endswith('.wav')
        ]
    for filename in filenames:
        call(['lame', '-V0',
              os.path.join(path, filename),
              os.path.join(path, '%s.mp3' % filename[:-4])
              ])
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    status = main()
    sys.exit(status)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what i came up with so far

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

lamedir = 'lame'
searchdir = "/var/test"
name = []

for f in os.listdir(searchdir):
    name.append(f)

for files in name:
    iswav = files.find('.wav')
    #print files, iswav
    if(iswav >0):
        print lamedir + ' -h -V 6 ' + searchdir + files + ' ' + searchdir + files[:iswav]+'.mp3'
        os.system(lamedir + ' -h -V 6 ' + searchdir + files + " " + searchdir +  files[:iswav]+".mp3")
```